# Definitions for gradle Transform API scopes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle's [transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api) defines a number of scopes. However, there is little documentation regarding what each scope means. Does anyone know?

```
/**
 * The scope of the content.
 *
 * <p/>
 * This indicates what the content represents, so that Transforms can apply to only part(s)
 * of the classes or resources that the build manipulates.
 */
enum Scope {
    /** Only the project content */
    PROJECT(0x01),
    /** Only the project's local dependencies (local jars) */
    PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS(0x02),
    /** Only the sub-projects. */
    SUB_PROJECTS(0x04),
    /** Only the sub-projects's local dependencies (local jars). */
    SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS(0x08),
    /** Only the external libraries */
    EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES(0x10),
    /** Code that is being tested by the current variant, including dependencies */
    TESTED_CODE(0x20),
    /** Local or remote dependencies that are provided-only */
    PROVIDED_ONLY(0x40);

    private final int value;

    Scope(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Given that the Android N source code hasn't been released yet, there aren't a lot of good examples to read over. The best that I've found so far is [realm-java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/realm-transformer) which contains a couple transformers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried out a number of different combinations of scopes. And determined the following;

- PROJECT: This scope represents the targeted gradle module.
- PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS: Dependencies inside the target module's "libs" folder
- SUB_PROJECTS: Dependencies inside the same android studio project, such as other gradle modules. For example, this *does not* allow us to analyze picasso's class files.
- SUB_PROJECTS_LOCAL_DEPS: Local "libs" files for dependencies inside the same android studio project.
- EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES: Libraries pulled from maven. For example, this *does* allow us to analyze picasso's class files.

Comment: Update: got a response from adt-dev. Confirms my observations.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/IdqxwvWaLb8